# egrep, get Salt from /etc/shadow

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to grep the Salt from /etc/shadow for the user test.

```
egrep -o "test:(.*$){1}" /etc/shadow --color
```

Which returns me:

```
test:$6$zy513.E6$ae7nXcZnVFb0f2H.x9I7xXTwJLZJzQtTzsdfkOSnZ7KiFxR.slWFPogXcnwZdGI9AW1n9EhFtBmozfxPebXbB0:16882:0:99999:7:::
```

Actually I wanted the following, the Salt:

```
test:$6$zy513.E6$
```

Does anyone know how to fix my `egrep`? I could not find a Solution for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Escape your dollar sign.  `egrep -o 'test:(.*\$){1}'`. In regex, a dollar sign means the end of the line.

Comment: @ghoti : I agree with you. However in my system `\$` is not working, but `[$]` is.

Comment: @blackSmith - sure, that works too. Putting special characters inside a range (i.e. square brackets) removes their specialness. This works for period, question mark, plus and asterisk and carat as well (`[.?+*^]`). (Though remember that if a carat is at the beginning of the range, it inverts the range, so that `[^0-9]` means "any character that is not a digit".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one:

`egrep -o 'test:(\$[^$]+){2}\$' /etc/shadow --color`

Comment: It doesn't work because you are using double quotes. In double quotes the shell expands the `$`. The first example does work only because the `$` does not need to get escaped in a regex when used inside a character class, however the \ prevents the shell from expanding it.

Comment: Ok I got it. I edited my answer to take in consideration your explanation, thank you.

Comment: Erm... Double quotes shouldn't be an issue as long as the characters following the `$` cannot be interpreted as a variable or deprecated arithmetic expression.  Check it out: `echo "$][$"`.  Of course, neither figuring out what characters count as variables nor determining what needs escaping is a task for bash novices. :-)   `egrep -o "test:(\\\$[^$]+){2}\\$" /etc/shadow` .. note the unescaped dollar sign inside the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F: '{gsub(/\$[^$]+$/, "$",$2);print $1,$2}' OFS=: /etc/shadow
```

`-F:` sets the field delimiter to `:`, this makes it simple to access the password portion in field 2 (`$2`).

The regex used by `gsub()` is replacing everything after the last dollar until the end of the strings by the dollar.

Output:

```
test:$6$zy513.E6$
```

Btw, the `$6` portion is not the salt, it is the type of hash algorithm used to hash the password, `6` stands for `SHA-512`. The salt is `zy513.E6`

Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file) for more information.

---

Update:

If you are searching only for a certain user, in this case `test` change the `awk` command to:

```
awk -F: '$1=="test" {gsub(/\$[^$]+$/, "$",$2);print $1,$2}' OFS=: /etc/shadow
```

Comment: I wanted just a single User, since i didnt worked with awk before no idea where i should change stuff so it only gives me the Single user i mentioned before.

Comment: Use `awk -F: '/username/{gsub(/\$[^$]+$/, "$",$2);print $1,$2}' OFS=: /etc/shadow` then